Installing a StrongSwan VPN on Ubuntu 22.04 - or how do I get the DNS server right
I try to migrate from Windows to Linux and am quite a noob. Hence, please don't be rude, if my question is a bit broad, I'm currently quite overwhelmed by the sheer size of the Linux system.
I have a firewall and I want to create a VPN connection to that Firewall, so that i can access resources within the local network behind that firewall. The firewall serves also as DNS and my other clients (Windows and Android) connect without problems with VPN to the firewall and use the configured DNS (the firewall's internal ip).
If I understand it correctly, this is the Road Warrior scenario in Linux?
I set up StrongSwan via /etc/ipsec.conf (and corresponding files) and I'm able to successfully connect and access resources within the local network and also external networks.
However the DNS server is not changed to the configured DNS of the VPN (the local IP address of the firewall). I assume, there must be a way to let StrongSwan do this automatically, since my other clients (Android and Windows) do this also automatically (since it is configured so in the VPN configuration).
The articles I read in the internet also suggest, that this should work on Linux and I wonder, whether there is something special with Ubuntu 24-04's DNS resolution.
I also tried to add the DNS directly into the ipsec.conf file (as rightdns), but this also does not work. The only way I get it working is, via /etc/systemd/resolved.conf, but this feels extremely incorrect (and is not practical in my scenario, since most of the time, the VPN is off).
In my last attempts fiddling around, I even killed my whole Linux installation.
What is necessary to be configured, so that Ubuntu 24-04 uses the VPN's configured DNS server when the VPN is up?
For completeness, here my configuration (Logs I currently do not have, since I killed my installation and must reinstall it).
conn vpn
    keyexchange=ikev2
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    leftauth=eap-mschapv2
    leftsourceip=%config
    leftfirewall=yes
    eap_identity="myUser"
    right=[the firewall's address]
    rightid=[the id]
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    rightauth=pubkey
    rightdns=[internal IP address of my local DNS]
    ike=aes256-sha512-modp1024
    esp=aes256-sha512
    auto=add


Highly recommend you look at https://github.com/trailofbits/algo. It’s geared most towards deploying into cloud infrastructure, but if you look through the documentation you can find ways to deploy it on any pre-existing system - https://github.com/trailofbits/algo?tab=readme-ov-file#advanced-deployment. If you don’t use it “out of the box”, you can at least use it as a reference for how to properly (most securely) configure things
